# Does more data make convergence easier or more difficult?

Tags: optimization

Say we are trying to solve some optimization problem $$\min_p \sum_{i = 1}^N L(p; x_i)$$

using gradient descent, where $L$ is some loss function.

My question is, what happens when we increase $N$?

- On one hand, the algorithm will suffer, because we need to do more work to e.g. calculate the gradients. I know this is true.
- But on the other hand, won't each gradient contain "more information" in some way? So shouldn't that help us convergence faster? Or does more $N$ make the problem more complex in some way, so that even if your gradient contains more information, it isn't enough to make up for the added complexity? I don't really know what is true here.